# Comparing hash function doesn't compare accurately

Tags: android

i want to compare two hash function with user input. If both equals then Toast me. The purpose of this, i want to use this methodology in future for storing my hash password to database and compare with user input password for login.

I making two input types in which i give string value by input and convert it to hash value. It should be Toast me when both input types have same value, if not then don't Toast me or give me error.

The problem is when i give same values it Toast me accurately but when i give two different values it also Toast me. which is not correct result.

Kindly tell me how to compare both functions and make login scenario.

The code is:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        value1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value1);
        value2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value2);

        computeSha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        //get username and password entered
        username = userName.getText().toString();
        passwd = passWord.getText().toString();

        //check if username or passwd is not null

        if ((username != null && username.equals("")) || (passwd != null && passwd.equals(""))) {

            computeSha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //call method to compute SHA hash
                    computeSHAHash(value1);
                    computeSHAHash(value2);
                    if (computeSHAHash(value1).equals(computeSHAHash(value2))) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private String convertToHex(byte[] data) throws java.io.IOException
    {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String hex=null;

        hex=Base64.encodeToString(data, 0, data.length, NO_OPTIONS);

        sb.append(hex);

        return sb.toString();
    }


    public String computeSHAHash(String password)
    {
        MessageDigest mdSha1 = null;
        try
        {
            mdSha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            Log.e("myapp", "Error initializing SHA1 message digest");
        }
        try {
            mdSha1.update(password.getBytes("ASCII"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] data = mdSha1.digest();
        try {
            SHAHash=convertToHex(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        result.setText("SHA-1 hash generated is: " + " " + SHAHash);
        return SHAHash;
    }
```

Hashing function:

```
private String convertToHex(byte[] data) throws java.io.IOException
    {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String hex=null;

        hex=Base64.encodeToString(data, 0, data.length, NO_OPTIONS);

        sb.append(hex);

        return sb.toString();
    }


    public String computeSHAHash(String password)
    {
        MessageDigest mdSha1 = null;
        try
        {
            mdSha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            Log.e("myapp", "Error initializing SHA1 message digest");
        }
        try {
            mdSha1.update(password.getBytes("ASCII"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] data = mdSha1.digest();
        try {
            SHAHash=convertToHex(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        result.setText("SHA-1 hash generated is: " + " " + SHAHash);
        return SHAHash;
    }
```